# Haskell binary tree parsing

Tags: haskell, tree, binary

I am learning about building and parsing binary trees in Haskell and I found a program example that I can't quite understand how works.. So the code is:

```
module Main where

data TTT aa = Leaf [aa] | Node (TTT aa) (TTT aa)  deriving (Show,Eq);

a :: Num a => Integer -> Integer; 
a x = x^2; 

ff_a :: TTT Integer -> TTT Integer; 
ff_a t = mm a t; 

mm :: (Integer -> Integer) -> TTT Integer -> TTT Integer; 
mm f (Node a1 a2) = Node(mm f a1) (mm f a2); 
mm f (Leaf n) = Leaf(new_mm f n); 

new_mm :: (Integer -> Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]; 
new_mm f (a:a1) = f a : new_mm f a1; 
new_mm f [] = []; 

tree =   
    Node   
        (Node   
            (Node   
                ((Leaf[16,-5,19]))
                ((Leaf[14,24,-55,27]))
            )  
            (Node   
                ((Leaf[37,11,64]))
                ((Leaf[-14,6,29]))
            )  
        )  
        (Node   
            (Node   
                ((Leaf[10,-19,22]))
                ((Leaf[3,4,5,-7]))
            )  
            (Node   
                ((Leaf[31,29,13]))
                ((Leaf[18,38,-4]))
            )  
        )  


main :: IO ();

t0 = tree      
t1 = ff_a tree 

main = do

    print t0;
    print t1;
```

Could someone explain to me how really functions `mm` and `new_mm` work? And what does `Integer -> Integer` and `TTT integer -> TTT integer` means and what data type is that?

Comment: `new_mm` is by definition equal to the function [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). The type signature however is restricted to `Integer`.
`mm` seems to be a variant of map, working for the `TTT` definition of binary trees (which have list leaves).

Comment: In case you would like to learn more about algebraic data types, which is given here by the `data TTT aa = ...` definition, I recommend to read the relevant section of [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types).

Answer (score 2):

The code as shown in the OP doesn't compile, but it's fairly easy to fix. Change `a` to:

```
a :: Integer -> Integer; 
a x = x^2;
```

(BTW, the semicolons are redundant and should be removed. It's not idiomatic Haskell to end each line with a semicolon.)

> Could someone explain to me how really functions "mm" and "new_mm" work?

`mm` depends on `new_mm`, so let's start there. A common way to get a sense of how and what Haskell code does is to experiment with it in GHCi.

```
*Main> new_mm a []
[]
*Main> new_mm a [1,2,3]
[1,4,9]
*Main> new_mm (\i -> i + 1) [1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
```

The `new_mm` function translates each value in the input list according to a function argument. It's just the built-in `map` function implemented from scratch and restricted to work only on `Integer`. If you need to understand how the `map` implementation works, I'm sure that your Haskell learning resource contains an explanation.

The `mm` function just 'elevates' the mapping function to work on the `TTT` data structure.

```
*Main> mm a (Leaf [])
Leaf []
*Main> mm a (Leaf [1,2,3])
Leaf [1,4,9]
*Main> mm (\i -> i + 1) (Leaf [1,2,3])
Leaf [2,3,4]
*Main> mm (\i -> i + 1) (Node (Leaf [1,2,3]) (Leaf [4,5,6]))
Node (Leaf [2,3,4]) (Leaf [5,6,7])
```

> And what does Integer -> Integer and TTT integer -> TTT integer means and what data type is that?

`Integer -> Integer` indicates a function that takes an `Integer` as input and which return an `Integer`.

`TTT Integer -> TTT Integer` (notice that I changed the case), likewise, means a function that takes a `TTT Integer` value as input and which returns a `TTT Integer` value.